# Incremental import of git-fast-import stream to Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, git-fast-import, reposurgeon

I am in the process of converting a few older repositories and splicing and dicing them as needed to get one future repository. A bit of scar tissue in the history (most of them due to semantics in the previous VCS) had to be removed as well, but all in all the conversion seems to be smooth.

It just takes very long.

Background: I am using `reposurgeon`, which works based on `git-fast-import` streams. Target format is Mercurial.

How can I import new increments of code introduced into the old VCSs while they are still live, such that I don't have to run through the full conversion routine every time?

Comment: Did you have any luck yet with that? Do you use reposurgeon just for splitting up at predefined commit points, or does it help mixing the bi-directional syncs? Couldn't `--export/import-marks` still speed it up? (Maybe you could share again a few pieces of your fast-export + reposurgeon config/scripting.)

Comment: @mario back then the effort got abandoned, but due to Bitbucket discontinuing support for Hg, I am actually planning on picking it up for other projects. If so, I'll update the question (or even answer it).